# "Submissions in TeX"

Tags: publishing

I'm getting ready to submit my first paper, and I have a stupid question -- if a journal's guidelines say that they want "submissions in TeX," does that mean that I can submit a LaTeX source file, or do I have to rewrite my paper in plain TeX?

Comment: I think the answer to the question would depend on the journal... Why don't you ask them?

Comment: Is it reasonable to close as too localized?

Comment: Only Donald Knuth still uses plain TeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am extremely confident that they will accept and most likely prefer LaTeX, and they simply were imprecise in writing their submission guidelines. I base this on the fact that LaTeX is extremely widespread in the mathematical world and is what every journal I have dealt with expected.

But, if you want, you certainly could e-mail the editor to check.

Comment: Indeed, journals usually have Latex style files to use in the submission.